# Add a class to collection_select in Rails haml template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

We have the following in a haml template and are trying to apply a class to the drop-down field, but can't seem to figure it out.

```
 = f.collection_select(:thing_id, Thing.all, :id, :name, include_blank: true)
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: How about this `= f.collection_select(:thing_id, Thing.all, :id, :name, include_blank: true class: 'select-class')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work ->

```
= f.collection_select(:thing_id, Thing.all, :id, :name, include_blank: true, class: 'your_class_name')
```

Comment: Please update your answer with more details so it'll be helpful to future readers.

Comment: So bizarre, I thought we'd tried this but maybe not.  Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The above answer didn't work in rails 4.2.0. But this did:

```
= f.collection_select(:thing_id, Thing.all, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, {class: 'your_class_name'})
```

Options and html_options should be a hash.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select